# Calling a modal after a success ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation

Hi currently I'm using jQuery Validator plugin to validate my forms, all are running fine but when I have a success call in Ajax, I want to call a modal (bootstrap) seems is not firing the code inside success, this happened when I use the validator embedded function ifprevented, if I use e.defaultPrevent the validation works partially it triggers the PHP call ignoring the validation and modals work fine but if I use where the documentation says use the isdefaultPrevented validations work great but cant fire the modal here is the script I'm using it. Thank you in advance.

```
  $('#candidateForm').validator().on('submit', function(e) {
    if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        // handle the invalid form...
    } else {
        var dataString = $('#candidateForm').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "work/php/onlineApplication/addNewCandidate.php",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result['data'].status);
                if (result['data'].status == 'error') {
                    $("#bodyMsgModal").html(result['data'].message);
                    $("#addUserModal").modal();
                    $(result['data'].Field).focus();
                }
                if (result['data'].status == 'success') {
                    $("#bodyMsgModalSuccess").html(result['data'].message);
                    $("#addUserModalSuccess").modal();
                    $('#candidateForm')[0].reset();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Is `'#candidateForm'` a link (`a` tag) element by chance?

Comment: no is not, thats the html form

Comment: Does this ajax works? If so, put a function on 'error' callback and check what returns there..

Comment: Yed Ajax is working in fact either is i use the intégrate función from validator stills works the only thing broke are modal call

Comment: Wait, shouldnt that be `$("#addUserModal").modal('show');` ?.... note the `'show'`

Comment: It xab be either way, but i haven't tru with this code i'll check, just tobrrmaind if i override isdefsultprevented modals works but post goes thru even if field form are wrong

Comment: @DelightedD0D I changed to use 'show' same thing, I notice that is not triggering the console.log

Comment: I found a solution but don't know if the best way to used, the thing I did was to put preventDefault(); right after the else, thanks for all helped me :) cheers